# Javascript string literals in functions

Tags: javascript

Just asking to clarify. If I have a string literal inside of a function, is it "recreated" every time I call the function? Let's say I have this:

```
function myFunc(){
    var a = otherFunc("string1"),
        b = someFunc("this is quite a long string isn't it? yes, yes it is");

    // Some other code
}
```

Do those strings get recreated on every call, or just when I declared the function?

Comment: That depends on the Javascript engine and its optimisation techniques.

Comment: do you recommend storing the string in a variable if the said function will be used quite a lot?

Comment: I recommend you profile your code to figure out if this is a bottleneck at all before spending one more second worrying about it.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'm don't really have a project right now. Just wondering if I've been doing it wrong all this time.